# Admob Admediation networks not delivering iAds

Tags: ios, ipad, admob, iad

I am using AdMob in my iPad App, and I have configured various AdMediation Networks in my AdMob app settings. These networks also include the iAd Network. But unfortunately, AdMob is not delivering iAds. Instead, it is delivering default placeholder ad. Am I missing something? Do I need to do any settings in code to integrate iAds? Here is the screenshot of ad I am getting.
[image]

Comment: Do you mean an AdMob placeholder ad, or the iAd test ad? Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: its AdMob place holder ad not iAd. Here is the screenshot.

Comment: have you set the frequency of iAd in Admob?

Comment: Sorry, how do I set frequency for iAd in AdMob Settings? In mediation networks I setup 100% to iAd and turned off rest of the AdNetworks. Then it is showing me only one ad.